# Word: Picture hidden behind text

Tags: ms-word

Since this problem is reoccurring in my workflow and the solution is hard to find:

When pasting pictures into a MS Word document, sometimes it disappears behind the text, at least when working in the *Print Layout*. Sometimes also the text disappears and only part of the image is visible.

Comment: dear downvoter, could you please provide a reason for the downvote so that I can improve the question?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. Select the image (if you cannot select it, change the view)
2. Go to `Home` > `Paragraph` > `Line Spacing Options`. A dialog box will appear.
3. Change the Line spacing from `Exactly` to anything else
4. Click OK